# Install PECL on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard, pecl

Is there any way to install PHP:s PECL handler on Mac OS X 10.6, to be used with the bundled PHP?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Better late than never, but if you are like me and installed PHP directly from php.net (instead of using something like Homebrew or Port, then you can simply follow the following link to install Pear and PECL:

http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/

> We need PEAR! For some reason, it's not set up ready to on Lion, but
>   the install phar file is here, so we just need to run it.
>
> ```
> cd /usr/lib/php
> sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar
>
> Edit:
> /etc/php.ini and find the line: ;
>   include_path = ".:/php/includes" 
> and change it to:
>   include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php/pear"
> sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
> sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
> sudo pear upgrade-all
> ```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: I would say that editing `php.ini` is not necessary, because default `include_path` value seems to be already pointing to PEAR directories.

Comment: if you have mavericks please follow the following tutorial http://akrabat.com/computing/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-mavericks/

Answer (score 1):

Try installing it via:

```
bash <(curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh)
```

---

Or install by hand:

```
curl -s -o /tmp/packager.tgz http://php-osx.liip.ch/packager/packager.tgz
sudo tar -C /usr/local  -xzf /tmp/packager.tgz
```

Then install packer:

```
sudo /usr/local/packager/packager.py install 5.4-frontenddev
```

otherwise update it via:

```
sudo /usr/local/packager/packager.py install tools-frontenddev # Ignore
```